# How to avoid PHP Notice: Get cart should not be called before the wp_loaded action

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, cart

I would like to do a phone OTP verfication in woocommerce checkout page only for products in "lms" category, then I create this snippets:

```
function hkioh_is_lms_product_in_cart() {
    
    global $woocommerce;
    
    if (! $woocommerce->cart)
        return false;

    if ( $woocommerce->cart->is_empty())
        return false;
    
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) 
    {
        $product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id();
        $categories = get_the_terms($product_id, 'product_cat');
        if (is_array($categories)) 
        {
            foreach ($categories as $category) 
            {
                if ($category->slug === 'lms') 
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return false;
} 



add_filter( 'xoo_ml_get_phone_forms', function( $forms ){

    if( !hkioh_is_lms_product_in_cart() ){

        foreach ($forms as $index => $data) {

            if( $data['key'] === 'woocommerce-process-checkout-nonce' ){

                            unset($forms[$index]);

            }

        }

    }

    return $forms;

} );


add_action( 'wp', function(){

    if( !is_checkout() || hkioh_is_lms_product_in_cart() ) return;

    remove_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field', array( xoo_ml_phone_frontend(), 'wc_checkout_otp_field_html' ), 10, 4 );

    remove_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , array( xoo_ml_phone_frontend(), 'wc_checkout_add_otp_field' ), 9999 );

} );
```

It works but the debug.log keep giving me the following notices:

[26-Nov-2023 06:17:33 UTC] get_cart was called incorrectly. Get cart should not be called before the wp_loaded action. Backtrace: require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, Xoo_Ml_Phone_Verification->request_otp, Xoo_Ml_Phone_Verification::is_a_phone_form, apply_filters('xoo_ml_get_phone_forms'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, {closure}, hkioh_is_lms_product_in_cart, WC_Cart->is_empty, WC_Cart->get_cart, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 2.3.

I have tried to change add_action( 'wp', ... to add_action('wp_loaded',... but cannot solve the issue.  So any idea? thanks.

Comment: Your traceback shows that you're calling it on the `init` action via the `request_otp` method. The code you pasted actually works. Paste your `request_otp` code instead as that's where the error is from, it's accessing `hkioh_is_lms_product_in_cart` too early.